# Run tasks with a certain tag within role in Ansible

Tags: ansible, tags, roles

I have the following folder-structure, inspired by the best-practices section in Ansibles documentation:

```
my-playbook.yml
my-role
   |
   |── tasks
         |
         |── my-task.yml
```

I have tagged the tasks within the my-task.yml file which is part of a role. I execute the playbook using ansible-playbook.yml --tags "mytag". Unfortunately, all tasks are skipped. Can I only filter tasks directly part of the playbook?

Within my playbook, I do something like

```
- hosts: ansible_server
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no
  roles:
   - validate_properties
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you need to include the tasks in the main.yml as that is the default file called during the role execution.

Answer (score 1):

What you should do is call the `role` from a `task` by using the `include_role` module. On that `task` you can apply `tags`. Take this `playbook`, for example:

```
---
- name: Tag role test
  hosts: local
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - include_role:
        name: debug
      tags:
        - dont_run

    - debug:
        msg: Solo shot first
      tags:
        - run
```

Where my `role/debug` consists of just a task that prints `Hello, world!`.

If you call this `playbook` directly you get this output:

```
PLAY [Tag role test]

TASK [debug : debug] 
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg: Hello, world!

TASK [debug] 
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg: Solo shot first

PLAY RECAP
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

But, if you exclude the `dont_run` task like this:

```
ansible-playbook tag_roles.yml --skip-tags dont_run
```

This is the output:

```
PLAY [Diff test] 

TASK [debug] 
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg: Solo shot first

PLAY RECAP 
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You have to tag the subtasks also with your tag u want to run to:
Main Task:

```
- name: "test tags on sub task"
  include_tasks: subtask.yml
  with_items: "{{ myList }}"
  loop_control:
    label: item
  tags: test
```

Sub task:

```
debug: msg="Sub Task"
tags: test
```